# Extracting user details from facebook page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jsoup

I am extracting details from a page which I'm administering. I tried using jsoup to extract the links then from that extract names of users but it's not working. It only shows links other than user links. I tried extracting names from this link

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=pageid

which is working quite well but does not works for this link

https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=

Can anyone help me...Below is the code which I tried.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=mypageid").get();
Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("fsl fwb fcb");
Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");

for(Element ele : link)
{
    system.out.println(ele.attr("href"));

} }
```

Comment: What details you are expecting from a page? Can not you use graph apis??

Comment: i am expecting output like the list of users who like my own facebook page

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=pageid").timeout(0).get();

        Elements nameLinks = doc.getElementsByClass("link");
        for (Element users : nameLinks) {
        String name = users.attr("title");
        String url = users.attr("href");

        System.out.println(name + "-" + url);

        }
```

It will give all the users name and URl present on the first link defined in your question.

Comment: @kaduva accept it. If u find the solution your are looking for.

Comment: it's not showing the expected output. Using this i can extract only a max of 100 even if i can get max of 500 users since i'm administering this page

Comment: So instead of this url use url of the page which is showing all 500 users. Or show me the url where you can see all 500 users.

Comment: this is the link..but only i can see all users since i'm the administrator of this page.....try this https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=mypageid

Comment: i have already mentioned that i can extract deetails from this link https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=pageid....I want to get it from the page i specified...read my question carefully

Comment: Sir i have already read the question carefully even when you haven't defined it well. I can give you the solution with what inputs I have. So better now you try it your own as I have already provide u the snippet that how to parse it. This site is not for spoon feeding. Try to put some efforts by you own as well.